# TextField: text is cropped a bit when its width is greater than the width of TextField

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The text is above the `TextField`, when text's width is lower than `TextField`'s width.

[image: width lower]

But the text is cropped by the `TextField`, when text's width is greater than `TextField`'s width.

[image: width greater]

Is it possible to do something in order to display the text always above?

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    TextField {
        id: textField1
        x: 25
        y: 163
        width: 62
        height: 20
        font.pixelSize: 20
        placeholderText: qsTr("Text Field")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reason for not fitting the size of TextField to the font size?

Comment: This looks like a bug in `TextField`, but I agree with @DenimPowell in that this is an odd use case (deliberately clipping text).

Comment: I don't think this is a bug.  cropping is needed to hide the left side of the text when overflowed.

Comment: It's just an illustrative example. In my app `TextField`'s height is a bit greater than text's. So all is OK when the string is short(text in the rectangle https://yadi.sk/i/nmkFDFM7iCxbF ). But when the string is long it's clipped https://yadi.sk/i/ELJUUkDfiCxbD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height of TextField not to crop the text and make its background rect small.

```
TextField {
    id: textField1
    x: 25
    y: 163
    width: 62
    height: 30
    font.pixelSize: 20
    placeholderText: qsTr("Text Field")

    style: TextFieldStyle {
        textColor: "black"
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 2
            color: "transparent"

            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height / 2
                border.width: 1
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                radius: 2
                border.color: "steelblue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```